# Adding and removing SVM parameters without having to totally retrain

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have a support vector machine trained on ~300,000 examples, and it takes roughly 1.5-2 hours to train this model, and I pickled(serialized) it. Currently, I want to add/remove a couple of the parameters of the model. Is there a way to do this without having to retrain the entire model? I am using sklearn in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `SVC` from sklearn then the answer is no. There is no way to do it, this implementation is purely batch training based. If you are training linear SVM using `SGDClassifier` from sklearn then the answer is yes as you can simply start the optimization from the previous solution (when removing feature - simply with removed corresponding weight, and when adding - with added any weight there).